# как вызывать уведомления посредством AlarmManager?

Tags: android

есть два класса

первый - `AlarmManager` - вызывает событие с определенным интервалом,

второй - `NotificationManager` - выводит непосредственно уведомления.

по-отдельности оба класса работают корректно, но не могу их объединить, чтоб через определенный интервал в классе с `AlarmManager` вызывался метод из класса `NotificationManager`

первый класс

```
package com.example.reminder;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class ReminderManager extends BroadcastReceiver{
    ReminderNotifications rn = new ReminderNotifications();
    final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";
    Random random = new Random();
    int time;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR_TAG");
        wl.acquire();

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

        //rn.MyNotification(); //метод из второго класса, при вызове приложение прерывается
        Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        wl.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context){
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderManager.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        time = random.nextInt(1000 * 10) + 1000;
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), time, pi);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderManager.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

второй класс

```
package com.example.reminder;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class ReminderNotifications extends AppCompatActivity{
    private final static int NOTIFY_ID = 101;

    public void MyNotification(){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderNotifications.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setTicker("Attention")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                .setContentText("Пора уходить домой");

        Notification notification = builder.getNotification(); //до 16 API
        //Notification notification = builder.build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

прошу извинить, если проблема слишком тривиальная, но сам пока не разобрался

Comment: может поможет sceleton ?

Comment: @Saidolim, к сожалению, не совсем понимаю о чем Вы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` ничего не знает о ваших активити, он создается системой в своем собственном контексте, который передается в метод `onReceive()`. Вот этот контекст и надо использовать для создания уведомлений.

Именно по этой причине Ваш код с уведомлениями не так и просто переиспользовать из `BroadcastReceiver`.

Просто вынесите его отдельно от активити, контекст можно передать как параметр, тогда все получится.

Comment: то есть, уведомления не использовать отдельным классом, а прописать как метод в классе с AlarmManager? и интентом передать Context из onResieve и получить в методе с уведомлениями?

Comment: В каком классе это не суть важно, важно чтобы метод был независим от контекста, что-то типа `makeNotification(Context context)`. Потом вызывайте его хоть из активити, хоть из `onReceive()`, передавая правильный контекст. В Вашем случае можно этот метод сделать и статическим.

Comment: да, спасибо большое, все запустилось))